# Error while compiling - after checkinstall two ERRORs accoured

Tags: compilation, tor, checkinstall

I would like to compile the newest version of tor (0.2.7.6) but I haven`t done compiling yet. I am stuck with this.
I've done:

> ./configure (went ok)
>   make (went ok)
>   sudo checkinstall (Error)

After checkinstall the following Errors accoured:

```
Debian@Debian:~/tor-0.2.7.6$ sudo checkinstall --install=no

checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.



*****************************************
**** Debian package creation selected ***
*****************************************

This package will be built according to these values: 

0 -  Maintainer: [ root@RPI1Tor ]
1 -  Summary: [ tor_0.2.7.6-self_compiled ]
2 -  Name:    [ tor ]
3 -  Version: [ 0.2.7.6 ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ armhf ]
8 -  Source location: [ tor-0.2.7.6 ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ tor ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]

Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 

Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
  CC       src/or/networkstatus.o
  CC       src/or/nodelist.o
  CC       src/or/onion.o
  CC       src/or/onion_fast.o
  CC       src/or/onion_tap.o
  CC       src/or/transports.o
  CC       src/or/policies.o
  CC       src/or/reasons.o
  CC       src/or/relay.o
  CC       src/or/rendcache.o
  CC       src/or/rendclient.o
  CC       src/or/rendcommon.o
  CC       src/or/rendmid.o
  CC       src/or/rendservice.o
  CC       src/or/rephist.o
  CC       src/or/replaycache.o
  CC       src/or/router.o
  CC       src/or/routerkeys.o
  CC       src/or/routerlist.o
  CC       src/or/routerparse.o
  CC       src/or/routerset.o
  CC       src/or/scheduler.o
  CC       src/or/statefile.o
  CC       src/or/status.o
  CC       src/or/torcert.o
  CC       src/or/onion_ntor.o
  AR       src/or/libtor.a
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-addressmap.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-buffers.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-channel.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-channeltls.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-circpathbias.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-circuitbuild.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-circuitlist.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-circuitmux.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-circuitmux_ewma.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-circuitstats.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-circuituse.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-command.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-config.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-confparse.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-connection.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-connection_edge.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-connection_or.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-control.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-cpuworker.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-dircollate.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-directory.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-dirserv.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-dirvote.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-dns.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-dnsserv.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-fp_pair.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-geoip.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-entrynodes.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-ext_orport.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-hibernate.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-keypin.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-main.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-microdesc.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-networkstatus.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-nodelist.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-onion.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-onion_fast.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-onion_tap.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-transports.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-policies.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-reasons.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-relay.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-rendcache.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-rendclient.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-rendcommon.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-rendmid.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-rendservice.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-rephist.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-replaycache.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-router.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-routerkeys.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-routerlist.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-routerparse.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-routerset.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-scheduler.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-statefile.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-status.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-torcert.o
  CC       src/or/src_or_libtor_testing_a-onion_ntor.o
  AR       src/or/libtor-testing.a
  CC       src/or/tor_main.o
  CCLD     src/or/tor
  CC       src/tools/tor-resolve.o
  CCLD     src/tools/tor-resolve
  CC       src/tools/tor-gencert.o
  CCLD     src/tools/tor-gencert
  CC       src/test/bench.o
  CCLD     src/test/bench
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_accounting.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_addr.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_address.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_buffers.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_cell_formats.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_cell_queue.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_channel.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_channeltls.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_checkdir.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_circuitlist.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_circuitmux.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_config.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_containers.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_controller.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_controller_events.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_crypto.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_data.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_dir.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_entryconn.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_entrynodes.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_guardfraction.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_extorport.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_hs.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_introduce.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_keypin.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_link_handshake.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_logging.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_microdesc.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_nodelist.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_oom.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_options.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_policy.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_pt.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_relay.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_relaycell.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_replay.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_routerkeys.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_routerlist.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_routerset.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_scheduler.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_socks.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_status.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_threads.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_util.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_helpers.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-test_dns.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test-testing_common.o
  CC       src/ext/src_test_test-tinytest.o
  CCLD     src/test/test
  CC       src/test/src_test_test_slow-test_slow.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test_slow-test_crypto_slow.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test_slow-test_util_slow.o
  CC       src/test/src_test_test_slow-testing_common.o
  CC       src/ext/src_test_test_slow-tinytest.o
  CCLD     src/test/test-slow
  CC       src/test/src_test_test_memwipe-test-memwipe.o
  CCLD     src/test/test-memwipe
  CC       src/test/test-child.o
  CCLD     src/test/test-child
  CC       src/test/src_test_test_workqueue-test_workqueue.o
  CCLD     src/test/test_workqueue
  CC       src/test/test_ntor_cl.o
  CCLD     src/test/test-ntor-cl
  CC       src/test/src_test_test_bt_cl-test_bt_cl.o
  CCLD     src/test/test-bt-cl
  CC       src/tools/tor-checkkey.o
  CCLD     src/tools/tor-checkkey
  GEN      doc/tor.1
  GEN      doc/tor-gencert.1
  GEN      doc/tor-resolve.1
  GEN      doc/torify.1
  GEN      doc/tor.html
  GEN      doc/tor-gencert.html
  GEN      doc/tor-resolve.html
  GEN      doc/torify.html
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/torpi/tor-0.2.7.6'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c src/or/tor src/tools/tor-resolve src/tools/tor-gencert '/usr/local/bin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c contrib/client-tools/torify '/usr/local/bin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/etc/tor'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/config/torrc.sample '/usr/local/etc/tor'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/doc/tor'
/bin/mkdir: das Verzeichnis „/usr/local/share/doc“ kann nicht angelegt werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:6122: recipe for target 'install-docDATA' failed
make[1]: *** [install-docDATA] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/torpi/tor-0.2.7.6'
Makefile:6613: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make: *** [install-am] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Prior to installing, can you run `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/doc` and then see if that step succeeds?

Comment: @drew010 - do you think that will work? I wonder because checkinstall don`t installs the package because of the `--install=no` option. I figured out that I properbly missed an option `--fstrans=yes`. Now I will try to create an .deb package with `checkinstall --fstrans=yes --install=no` and will install it after that.

Comment: Success!                                                                                              @drew101 - Your guessing was right! After I created this path it all went good.                                                                                                        Thank you!

Comment: Glad that worked, I'm not sure why it was able to create the other paths in /usr/local but not that one.  Either way, glad you are able to proceed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! @drew101 - Your guessing was right! After I created this path `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/doc` it all went good.

Thank you!